# Disable / Enable UIDatepicker

Tags: ios, xcode

Is there any disable/enable function in Xcode, i have already tried the hidden function but that really doesn't suit my needs. I'm trying to turn off my UIDatepicker if a uiswitch has been toggled and if it isn't toggled i want it shown. hiding this still outputs todays date to my mail composer. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you have a property (IBOutlet) for your UIDatepicker in your .h file 
then you can simply do like this:

```
DatePickerNamed.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
DatePickerName.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

In addition to that I also turn down the alpha value for buttons and switches, if I disable them, so there is also a visual feedback that they're inactive.

Comment: To turn down the alpha just      "DatePickerName.alpha = 0.5f;"