# Swift Date Picker object enable/disable

Tags: swift, datepicker, swift2, disabled-control

I want to disable a date picker object in swift 2. I already do this with UI objects and it works fine. E.g.:

```
dailyNotificationSwitch.enabled = false
```

When I try this with a date picker it does not have the same effect. Users can still use the date picker. When I disable a switch users can not use the button until it is enabled again.

Here my line for the date picker:

```
datePicker.enabled = false
```

Any suggestion what I am doing wrong or an explanation why I can't disable a date picker?

BR

Nikolay

Comment: `enabled` comes from `UIDatePicker`'s inheritance of `UIControl`, which should make it ignore touch events. That said, I'm guessing that somehow `UIDatePicker` has subviews that ignore this rule. `datePicker.userInteractionEnabled = false` should work just fine

Comment: @jimmyy: thanx for the explanation. Would you recommend the use of userInteractionEnabled rather than just enabled? is generelly better or saver?

Comment: I'd favor userInteractionEnabled just because it works. I'm not sure if enabled is accomplishing what you want it to.

Comment: With all man switches and sliders enabled works fine so far. I tested your suggestion and it did the job perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24530055/2415822