# How to disable react-native-datetimepicker in ios?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, datetimepicker, uidatepicker

I am using [react-native-datetimepicker](https://github.com/react-native-datetimepicker/datetimepicker) (@react-native-community/datetimepicker) for my android/ios app. I need to disable user from changing the date for some occasions.

In android since picker is only modal, anyway I have to show a label with date and I can disable user with onPress method logic.

But in ios a default label is given from the picker component and I need to disable it. I found following discussion on disabling the underlying ios component - [Disable / Enable UIDatepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24530055/disable-enable-uidatepicker)

I need to disable ios picker from `react-native-datetimepicker/datetimepicker` library.

Comment: how about checking "some occasions" then rendering a View instead of date picker

Comment: have a try with react-native-modal-datetime-picker NPM to set custom label for both platforms and customize enabling and disabling with login in onPress method